# asp.net c# Display few characters in gridview hyperlink

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Sorry in advance for the bad title!

I have a `gridview` where i use `sqldatasource`

The `gridview` has a field called cover letter and it is a link button
The title of the link button is view cover letter

[image]

```
<ItemTemplate>
 <asp:LinkButton ID="cat" runat="server" CommandName="cat" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("Id") %>' >View Cover Letter</asp:LinkButton>
 </ItemTemplate>
```

when i click on the view cover letter link a new window popup displaying the content of the cover letter

[image]

Now what i want to do is change the text of the link button from View Cover Letter so it display like the first 10 or 20 characters of the cover letter and when i click on the link it will show the full content of the cover letter in the new window.

so it will be something like this:

[image]

How can I do such a thing?

Comment: in which format you are saving the cover letter is it pdf or word or you are saving it in db?

Comment: It's saved in the database

Comment: you can try `Text=" Eval("coverLetter").ToString().Substring(0,20)"` as an attribute to bind the text for link button

Comment: So your code will be like `<ItemTemplate>
 <asp:LinkButton ID="cat" runat="server" CommandName="cat" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("Id") %>' Text="Eval("coverLetter").ToString().Substring(0,20)">View Cover Letter</asp:LinkButton>
 </ItemTemplate>`

Comment: @Nirzar im getting this error 

Parser Error 
  Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Comment: try using `Text='Eval("coverLetter").ToString().Substring(0,20)'` .... please see double quotes have been replaced to single quotes

Comment: It doesn't give error now but it shows like this 

https://imgur.com/a/MVqml

Comment: bro u have to specify the whole url try adding `~/` at the beginning of your url and upvote the answer if u like the same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154682/discussion-between-r-bandi-and-nirzar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your code will be like

`<ItemTemplate> <asp:LinkButton ID="cat" runat="server" CommandName="cat" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("Id") %>' Text='<%#Eval("coverLetter").ToString().Substring(0,20)%>'>View Cover Letter</asp:LinkButton> </ItemTemplate>`

Answer (score 1):

You can Use this: But make sure that you have some content in your cover letter content.. that was the reason you get the error.

```
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Cover Letter">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <a href='../Pages/CoverLetter.aspx?ID=<%# Eval("cover_id")%>' target="_blank" style="color: blue; text-decoration: underline"><%# Eval("cover_content").ToString().Length>10 ? Eval("cover_content").ToString().Substring(0,10):Eval("cover_content")%></a>
           </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: It gives this error



System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException occurred
  HResult=0x80131502
  Message=Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: length
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
   at System.String.Substring(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length)
   at ASP.pages_applied_aspx.__DataBind__control60(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\rek\HR_system\applyForOmicron\pages\applied.aspx:line 95

Comment: It's working 
https://imgur.com/a/JjpHH
but the new page is empty 

this is the code i have added:

<a href='../Pages/CoverLetter.aspx?ID=<%# Eval("Id")%>' target="_blank" style="color: blue; text-decoration: underline"><%# Eval("coverLetter").ToString().Length>10 ? Eval("coverLetter").ToString().Substring(0,10):Eval("coverLetter")%></a>

Comment: yes in new page you have to use request.querystring to get the value of ID parameter and run a sql query to get the content based on that ID.

Comment: Did you get it ?